# document.elementFromPoint returns null for a selected text

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to get the position of a selected text :

```
var text = window.getSelection(); 
start = text.anchorOffset; 
end = text.focusOffset - text.anchorOffset;
```

And I want to get that selected text later .. for that I am using :

```
document.elementFromPoint(start,end);
```

However, it always returns "null".

Help please :)

Answer (score 1):

[`elementFromPoint(start,end);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) requires xy page coordinates, you are passing index within a string.

To get the xy page coordinates you can use [Calculating xy-position of text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566323/calculating-xy-position-of-text-selection) .  Note that the coordinates are for the viewport, so you may have to account for scrolling if you want the distance from the top of the HTML document.

```
getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects()[0];
// ClientRect {}
// bottom: 226
// height: 15
// left: 300.75
// right: 305.078125    
// top: 211
```

width: 4.328125

To get the HTML element that wraps your text node, you can use [Get parent element of a selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215479/get-parent-element-of-a-selected-text)

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement
```

Comment: I don't understand .. how is getting the parent element of my selected text will help me to get its position ?

Comment: Your code was trying to find an element from a selection; I told you how to do that. Your question says nothing  about getting the position of the selected text

Comment: It does.
I said "to get the position of a selected text".
And I'm passing the two positions (start and end) to this function : document.elementFromPoint(start,end). 
My question was "Why does it return null ?" I want to get that text BY its position.

Comment: @Mayusu There is no element that corresponds to a text node, that's why your call returns null. I'm saying that the best you can do is to get the element that contains your selection

Comment: @Mayusu You should make your question title clearer by indicating what you are trying to do. I had answered the question that was asked in the title. I just added some comments that explain how to do what you really wanted